# When finding yearly compound interest why does Java compute interestRate/100 rather than just interestRate?

Tags: java

Here's the textbook problem:

> A certain bank offers 6.5% interest on savings accounts, compounded
>   annually. Create a table that shows how much money a person will
>   accumulate over a period of 25 years, assuming that the person makes
>   an initial investment of $1000 and deposits $100 each year after the
>   first. Your table should indicate for each year the current balance,
>   the interest, the new deposit, and the new balance.

This is my code. It is correct:

```
public void compoundAnnual() {
  double investment = 1000;
  int year = 25;
  double newDeposit = 0;
  double newBalance;
  double interestRate = 6.5;
  double interest;
  double deposit = 0;



    System.out.println("Year    Interest      New Deposit        New Balance");
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------");

    for (int i = 1; i <= year; i++) {
        if (i == 1)
        {

            newDeposit = investment;
        }
        newBalance = newDeposit * Math.pow((1 + (interestRate/100)), 1);

        interest = newBalance - newDeposit;

        System.out.printf("%1d    %10.2f   %20.2f    %22.2f \n ", i, interest, newDeposit, newBalance);


        newDeposit = newBalance + 100;            
    }    
}
```

However, when finding the newBalance I am confused why

```
Math.pow((1 + (interestRate/100)), 1);
```

is correct.

Why wouldn't

```
Math.pow((1 + (interestRate), 1);
```

be correct if interestRate was set to 0.65? When I set interestRate equal to 0.65 the output for this is wrong and I don't understand why. Wouldn't they be the same thing?

Comment: Oh yeah :D Thank you, brother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why wouldn't ... be correct if interestRate was set to 0.65?

Because `0.65` corresponds to 65% interest.

Try `0.065` (`= 6.5 / 100`).

(Note that this is nothing specific to programming, it's just arithmetic).

Comment: Showing the result of dividing 6.5 by 100 is hardly worth an answer

Comment: @JoakimDanielson arguably hardly worth a comment either ;)

Comment: Yeah, we're all wasting our time here :)

Answer (score 0):

interestRate should be `0.065` in your case not `6.5`, because `6.5/100=.065`.If you hard code interestRate as `6.5` you won't get expected output.

Try giving 
`interestRate =.065`
it will work fine.